# Present or Present Perfect in this sentence with an imaginary statement

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

I wrote:

> the associated organizations must act urgently in introducing a new word for a foreign word before it **has been widespread / becomes widespread / has become widespread / would been widespread / had been widespread / would have been widespread / would become widespread**

I guess I'm speaking an imaginary situation "before an imaginary word is widespread" (after the act have completely happened) or maybe it's just a fact. Do I need "would"?

Anyway, which tenses I mentioned are correct or more idiomatic?

Comment: *...must act urgently **by introducing** a new word...*  (or ***...to introduce...***) *...before it **becomes** widespread.* That's "Present tense verb as Future" (the "becoming widespread" is ***in the future*** relative to the need to act urgently).

Comment: You can use the past perfect in a future context, but you have to choose the right verb.  In this case "has been" does not sound natural.  I would change it to "has **become**".  Also, as a style choice, I prefer "act **to introduce**" rather than "act in introducing".

Comment: @Andrew Thanks, that's what I wanted to hear! but is it "past" or "present" perfect? you also used "has become"

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks, I edited the question a bit.

Comment: I think ***has become*** would be a bit ridiculous in the cited context. Stripped to its essentials, that would be like saying *I must go to bed before I **have fallen asleep*** instead of *...before I **fall asleep**.* And *...before I **would have fallen** asleep* is even worse.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you mean you can't find an example that present perfect fits better? because I feel "present perfect" shows an activity that has began in the past and its effect continues to the present (or maybe has finished). Now I am confused that "had become" or "had fallen asleep" may also work, because we want to say we must do something before that other action occurs completely (finishes or has effects to the moment we speak about)!

Comment: You should just forget about Perfect forms *unless you **need** them*. Which you don't, here. Just plain "Present as Future" is the idiomatically natural choice for your context *(X must do something before Y **happens**).*

Comment: If the entire "narrative context" is in the past: *X **needed to** do something before Y **happened***. Note that I switched from ***must*** to ***need to*** because you really don't want to get bogged down in "past" forms for the "degenerate" verb ***must***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Agreed.  I would have written the sentence differently. *"Has becoime"* is just my minimal edit to make the sentence sound more natural.